# an established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I am going to make my local vagrant machine online, i have done vagrant login successfully, but when i am trying to share my vagrant with command 
"vagrant share" its giving me error. error is attached as screenshot.

screenshot 1
screenshot 2
actually i am giving full view of error.
[image]
[image]